# Extract parent url from header with bash script

Tags: regex, bash, parsing

I have some time trying to get some part of a text (a header) on bash script but I couldn't. This is the string I have:

```
link: <https://api.some.com/v1/monitor/zzsomeLongIdzz?access_token=xxSomeLongTokenxx==>; rel="monitor",<https://api.some.com/v1/services/xx/something-more/accounts/2345?access_token=xxSomeLongTokenxx==>; rel="parent"
```

Here is with some format so you could see it better:

```
link: 
<https://api.some.com/v1/monitor/zzsomeLongIdzz?access_token=xxSomeLongTokenxx==>; rel="monitor",
<https://api.some.com/v1/services/xx/something-more/accounts/2345?access_token=xxSomeLongTokenxx==>; rel="parent"
```

I need the second part, just the `url`, basically the values between `,<` and `>; rel="parent"` and assign that to a variable, like:

```
my_url = $(echo $complete_header) <== some way to filter that
```

I have no idea how to apply some regex or pattern to extract the data I need. On the past I had use `jq` for filtering `json` responses, like this:

```
error_message=$(echo $response | jq '.["errors"]|.[0]|.["message"]')
```

But unfortunately for me, this is not a json. Could somebody point me on the right direction with that?

Comment: [`,<([^>]+)>`](https://regex101.com/r/hT5nL7/1) and use group 1.

Comment: @Jan Sorry, I have zero experience with bash, should I do this: `my_url = $(echo $complete_header,<([^>]+)> )`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
link='<https://api.some.com/v1/monitor/zzsomeLongIdzz?access_token=xxSomeLongTokenxx==>; rel="monitor",<https://api.some.com/v1/services/xx/something-more/accounts/2345?access_token=xxSomeLongTokenxx==>; rel="parent"'
re=",<([^>]+)>"
# look for ,< literally
# capture everything that is not a > one or more times ([^>]+)
# look for the closing > literally
my_url="test"
if [[ $link =~ $re ]]; then my_url=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; fi
echo $my_url
```

See [a demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/0v7r0M).

Comment: Thank you. Could yo point me to the `doc` in order to understand this `,<([^>]+)>`? Right now is a black box for me.

Comment: @Gepser: Glad to help. See the updated answer for an explanation.

Comment: @Gepser, `,<([^>]+)>` is a RegEx (Regular Expression) and in Jan's comment to your OP it is linked to an online regex tester and debugger which shows an explanation although that won't give you an in-depth  understanding of RegEx.  For that you'll need to read up on it.  Start by Googling: Understanding Regular Expressions  Also have a look at: http://regexone.com BTW Don't feel bad as RegEx feels like it was meant to be a Black Box by design. :)